# How to git-pull all but one folder

Tags: git

Is there any way to `git pull` all folders in the repository but one? I don't want to create a .gitignore file because other people may want the folder -- it's just too large for me to use right now.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think you can do partial pulling, but you can try and see what happen if you pull in a working tree which is not completely checked out.

Since [Git1.7](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.0/RelNotes-1.7.0.txt), you can do a [sparse checkout](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/v1.7.0/git-read-tree.html#_sparse_checkout), as [illustrated here](http://vmiklos.hu/blog/sparse-checkout-example-in-git-1-7), meaning your working tree would explicitly exclude that specific folder when populate its content.

Now if that directory is that big, it may be better to isolate it in an autonomous Git repository, allowing other users to refer to it as **[a submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update/1979194#1979194)**.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Thanks for the comment!

Answer (score 26):

If you want to get just   and  you could:

```
mkdir <repo>
cd <repo>
git init
git remote add -f origin <url>
git config core.sparsecheckout true
echo <dir1>/ >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
echo <dir2>/ >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
echo <dir3>/ >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
git pull origin master
```

I found a good reference [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210309072829/http://jasonkarns.com/blog/2011/11/15/subdirectory-checkouts-with-git-sparse-checkout/).

Comment: The reference link is no longer available.

Comment: what does <url> stand here for?

Comment: <url> in this case would be a URL for the repository. If you were hosting on GitHub it'd look something that looks like: https://github.com/organisation/repo-name.git