# Git post-receive hook. Move everything except a few folders

Tags: git, githooks

I have implemented a post-receive hook on my server (git was initialized with `git init --bare`). Hook was created in the following way:

```
cd repo/hooks/
touch post-receive
chmod 777 post-receive
```

Then inside of the file I have:

```
#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/var/www
export GIT_WORK_TREE
git checkout -f
```

Right now when I push my local changes everything gets moved to /var/www folder. The problem is that I do not want some of the folders to be moved. For example I have `folder1`, and `folder2` there which I do not want to be moved. Currently I am manually removing these folders after the push, but this is a ridiculous work and I would like to automate it.

I am on `ubuntu 14.04` / `git 2.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am manually removing these folders after the push

You could just ad this step in your hook

The other way is to try and [set up a sparse checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4909267/6309) (since you can [exclude folders in the `sparse-checkout` file](http://richsomerfield.com/blog/2014/03/05/adventures-in-git-sparsecheckouts/)).

```
echo "/*" > .git/info/sparse-checkout
echo "!folder1/" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
echo "!folder2/" >> .git/info/sparse-checkout
```

Comment: Can you please tell how can I add this step (removing these folders after the push) in my hook?

Comment: @SalvadorDali simply adin gthe command you are doing manually in the post receive script (after the checkout step): as a `rm -Rf /var/www/folder1`.

Comment: Got it. But if I will set up sparse checkout, these folders would not even be moved?

Comment: @SalvadorDali yes, that the idea of a sparse checkout: to *not* checkout everything.

Comment: Is there anything different I have to do if I am doing this in --bare repo? When I am doing the first command `echo "/*" > .git/info/sparse-checkout` I am getting No such file or directory

Comment: @SalvadorDali true, you would do this a non-bare repo only, so the first option (adding the rm step) is the easiest.