# How to make `sparse-checkout` effective during post-receive hook checkout?

Tags: git

My system is centos 7.4 with git 1.8.3.
Based on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26129796/7936836),I set `sparse-checkout` in my `remoteserver` bare repo as below:

```
!README.md
!.scrutinizer.yml
!.idea/*
!.idea_modules/*
/*
```

And I think permission is right:

```
[root@localhost info]# ls -al
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  44 Jan 28 11:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 7 root root 132 Jan 28 11:33 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 240 Jan 28 14:33 exclude
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  58 Jan 28 11:17 sparse-checkout
```

When I `git push remoteserver master` ,`post-receive` hook will run:
`git --work-tree="$DEPLOY_DIR"  --git-dir="$GIT_DIR" checkout -f`

The problem is :
`README.md` and `.scrutinizer.yml` still checkout.

How to make `README.md` and `.scrutinizer.yml` not checkout as setting in `sparse-checkout`?

Comment: Is sparse-checkout configured in the repo `$GIT_DIR`?

Comment: @ElpieKay,yes,`sparse-checkout` locate at  subfolder `info` of `$GIT_DIR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try first:

```
git --work-tree="$DEPLOY_DIR"  --git-dir="$GIT_DIR" config core.sparsecheckout true
```

Then your hook can go ahead and checkout the content, which should respect the `sparsecheckout` directive, with the [exclusions you have declared](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26129711/6309).

But: Git 1.8.3 is rather ancient: make sure and [upgrade it first if possible](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21820715/6309).

Comment: I tried 3 ways:1.recreate repo...2.run your script under remote repo...3.put your script in post-receive hook.no success.

Comment: @kittygirl in the remote repo folder, do you see a file name `config`? In that file, do you see a `core.sparsecheckout` line?

Comment: yes.`config` content are:`[core]
        repositoryformatversion = 0
        filemode = false
        bare = true
        autocrlf = false
        safecrlf = true
        sparsecheckout = true
`

Comment: @kittygirl Can you try in your hook a `git --work-tree="$DEPLOY_DIR"  --git-dir="$GIT_DIR" checkout -f --` (with a final ` --`) to force checkout of the files?

Comment: @kittygirl Also, can you test and delete `README.md` and `.scrutinizer.yml`, then try again to push and see if your hook does re-create those files, or keep them deleted from the working tree?

Comment: tried your last 2 comments,even I `rm -f README.md .scrutinizer.yml`,hook re-create those 2 files.Maybe that's a bug?

Comment: @kittygirl For testing, can you try and put `/*` in the first line, as I did back in 2014 in https://stackoverflow.com/a/25699265/6309?

Comment: @kittygirl Also for testing (as a separate test), can you replace `$GIT_DIR` by the full path to your bare repo on that remote server? Just to make sure you are referencing the right path.

Comment: After latest 2 tests,still same result.Now, I add `rm -f` in `post-receive` hook,no better choice.

Comment: @kittygirl The only explanation I can think of is related to the version of Git used: 1.8.3. Any change of upgrading it to 2.20.1? To test if the sparse checkout does work better with a more recent  version of Git.