# How to make a repo that has all configuration files but not pull changes to them afterwards

Tags: git

I have set up dev, staging, and live versions of a website which access different databases. All 3 sites are identical except for the config file. (and the changes I am working on)

The config file is where I specify which database I am accessing (test, staging, live) and I need this file in the repo because the site won't work without it.

But now every time I git pull it changes my database. If I put the config file in my .gitignore I get a merge complaint because the config is different.

What do I do?

Comment: Stop tracking your config file. Instead, track a template config file that you use once to create a new config file for each individual site.

Comment: Thanks, I will do that.

Comment: Uhhh I removed the config files from my gitlab and on my next pull it deleted the config files from my project.

Answer (score 0):

- Basically you want [gir sparse checkout](http://jasonkarns.com/blog/subdirectory-checkouts-with-git-sparse-checkout/).
- For more details read [Is it possible to do a sparse checkout without checking out the whole repository first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114887/is-it-possible-to-do-a-sparse-checkout-without-checking-out-the-whole-repository)

Comment: Sparse checkout would be the wrong tool. If you don't want to track that file, then don't track it.