# Repository containing child repositories

Tags: git, github

I'm working on uploading a bunch of old projects and samples from college and just proof-of-concepts I've done to my public Git account to give potential clients, head-hunters, etc. a look into the knowledge I know and work I've done outside of the closed "I can't show you" world of enterprise development.

I'm looking to create a couple master repos, for instance `college` for college assignments and `samples` for PoCs and tutorials I've done to solidify and learn new knowledge.

However, I do not want to upload each project as it's own repo. I have about 20 college projects and 10 sample projects I have locally and do not want to overload my GitHub account with 30 different repos.

Does anyone know of a way where I can create some kind of top-level repository in Git that just serves as an entry point into a bunch of Git projects that I *don't* want shown at the top-level of my account?

I've been looking into `git subprojects` and `git subtrees` but they don't seem to be the solution I'm looking for. I'm kind of trying to create a structure like this:

```
college (visible at top-level of profile)
    operating-system-threading-simulation 
    IBM360-assembly-calculator
    ...
samples (visible at top-level of profile)
   basic-node-server
```

As of now I've just been using a sub-folder system, but it doesn't give me the granularity I would like, say, if I wanted to modify `basic-node-server` but didn't want to work on the rest of the repository.

Any help is appreciated, and please let me know if this isn't a clear discription of what I'm looking for.

Comment: Maybe use partially checkouts (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114887/is-it-possible-to-do-a-sparse-checkout-without-checking-out-the-whole-repository) when you use your sub-folder-system?

Answer (score 1):

[Git's submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

Master-repo can to be always empty (have only submodules definitions), but, with correct submodules, "if you push master-repo, you push dependent-repos also"

PS - read doc carefully before playing with this toy