# Cloning a subdirectory of a repository off GitHub using Android Studio

Tags: android, git, github, repository

I was wondering whether it is possible to clone a subdirectory of a repository off GitHub using Android Studio? Usually when you clone a repository, you go "Check out project from Version Control" --> GitHub --> then you get something like this

[image]

However, for example, I would like to clone this subrepository as I would like to build the project and put it in my emulator. This address is https://github.com/hmkcode/Android/tree/master/android-material-design-appcompat.

I have tried to guess https://github.com/hmkcode/Android.git might have becomehttps://github.com/hmkcode/Android/android-material-design-appcompat.git, but this did not work.

Is it possible to clone this subrepository as I dont want the rest of the repository. I dont want to have to clone the whole thing and try to piece together the sub project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a "subrepo": it is just a subdirectory, and git reasons at the repo level.
You could use [sparse checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/600079/6309)  though, but it is not supported directly by Android studio. You would have to [prepare your local repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32274043/6309):

```
mkdir hacker-scripts
cd hacker-scripts
git init .
git config core.sparseCheckout true
echo 'android-material-design-appcompat/' > .git/info/sparse-checkout
git remote add -f origin https://...
git pull origin master
```