# Clone a git repository without checking out the whole repo - sparse checkout procedure?

Tags: git, sparse-checkout

I need access to a small number of directories in a git repository that is 250 GB.  Obviously checking out the whole thing is a big hit in time and disk space.  I cannot, however, find a working solution to how to get only the desired directories.  I can clone the whole thing and then enable sparse checkout, but that defeats the whole point.

I realize this has been asked a number of times:

[How do I clone a subdirectory only of a Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository)
[Is it possible to do a sparse checkout without checking out the whole repository first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114887/is-it-possible-to-do-a-sparse-checkout-without-checking-out-the-whole-repository)

but none of these (or other:  http://jasonkarns.com/blog/subdirectory-checkouts-with-git-sparse-checkout/) solutions work for me.

I'm running git 2.9.3 on a Fedora 25 machine.  I've tried the following to start, but I end up with the whole repo.  Changing the -f to -n for the last line has no effect.

```
mkdir <repo>
cd <repo>
git init
git remote add -f origin <url>
```

I've also tried this to no avail:

```
mkdir myrepo
cd myrepo  
git init
git config core.sparseCheckout true
git remote add -f origin git://...   #at this point, the whole repo comes down
echo "path/within_repo/to/desired_subdir/*" > .git/info/sparse-checkout
git checkout [branchname] # ex: master
```

(The same thing happens even if I execute the echo line before the git remote add line.)

Surely there is an easy solution for this that actually works, no?

EDIT:  Just for completeness, this is what I'm doing now based on comments.  Still have the same problem.

```
mkdir myrepo
cd myrepo  
git init
git config core.sparseCheckout true
echo "path/within_repo/to/desired_subdir/*" > .git/info/sparse-checkout
git remote add origin git://...   

git pull  #at this point, the whole repo comes down
```

Comment: The only thing I see here that is different from the tutorial is you are doing a checkout instead of a pull, try doing git pull origin master...

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  It is at the 5th step in my list that the whole repo is downloaded  I tried setting up the sparse-checkout file before git remote add... but that also did not work.  (I edited the question to reflect this comment.)

Comment: Don't add the `-f` on your `git remote add`. Instead, try pulling after the sparse checkout is done. Your remote will be set up, like a URL, but the fetch/pull can be done afterwards. It should respect the sparse checkout.

Comment: Sparse checkout is only about checkout. You cannot clone only the part that you are interested in. You can clone shallowly, but that still downloads at least one commit and a complete tree.

Comment: I'm sure my git nomenclature needs to be improved - I'll work on that.  My understanding is that checkout is for moving between branches of a cloned repo.  Is that correct?  From all this so far, it seems I'm not able to do what I want without pulling down the full repo.