# How to monitor changes to a specific subdirectory of a repository?

Tags: git, git-commit

I am interested in a git repository of some software/library (not owned or controlled by me, hosted on Github), also having the full repository checked out on my computer with git.

But I actually only care about changes in a **specific subdirectory** of the repository.

How can I monitor only the changes in that one subdirectory, when commits touch files in there?

Comment: Would codeowners be suitable https://help.github.com/articles/about-codeowners/

Comment: That is a great idea, unfortunately this is not _my_ repository (added above).

Comment: you can watch, but only repo, not subdirectory

Comment: That's where I am coming from Alexan. It is much to noisy :(

Comment: This would maybe qualify as an answer to my question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4909267/252627 (Unfortunately I can't post this as the question is now "on hold" because "offtopic")