# Removing/modifying static Qt resources in run-time

Tags: c++, qt, runtime, qt-designer, qresource

As part of a Qt Designer hacking, I'm interested in removing a resource in runtime (specifically `:/trolltech/widgetbox/widgetbox.xml`). Refer to the end of the post for more detail about the context.

My obvious (and failed) attempt was:

```
QFile(":/trolltech/widgetbox/widgetbox.xml").remove();
```

but it returned an error.

My next attempt was to use [`Q_CLEANUP_RESOURCE(widgetbox)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qdir.html#Q_CLEANUP_RESOURCE), but the functions it expands to are only available within a private component of Qt Designer (QDesignerComponents).

Another attempt was to clear the content of the file, but it is read-only:

```
QFile f(":/trolltech/widgetbox/widgetbox.xml");
if (f.open(QFile::WriteOnly)) { ... } // returns false
```

I've also tried to overwrite it in the Qt resource's filesystem by defining my own `:/trolltech/widgetbox/widgetbox.xml`. I'm able to open the file but it fails to retrieve data, I guess because it is a duplicate resource (aliasing the resource to an unused name makes the application to print out the content correctly). On the other hand, the list of widgets is presented correctly.

```
QFile f(":/trolltech/widgetbox/widgetbox.xml");
if (f.open(QFile::ReadOnly)) {
    qDebug() << "{";
    qDebug() << f.readAll(); // shows nothing
    qDebug() << "}";
}
```

Is there any way to modify/remove/replace a resource file in runtime?

---

In the case you consider this an [XY problem](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem) I'll explain the whole context: I'm integrating Qt Designer into my own IDE by making small tweaks to the standalone one. Basically, I've added a compilation flag to generate a dynamic library instead of an executable, and added some options to expose the main window.

In this IDE I want to add an option to avoid the user to use the default widgets and restrict the list to a set of custom ones. The resource I mention is the file containing the list of widgets available in Qt Designer by default. Additional widgets can be easily included via plugins, but I haven't found a way to remove default ones.

One option I have is to make that load optional, but it will produce a cascade of changes through many projects. I'd like to avoid modifying Qt Designer so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using Qt Designer already, so first of all you should include it in your build, and secondly you will have access to all of its classes - no such thing as a "private" component anymore, it's **your** code now. Make it work for you!

Qt resources can be compiled-in or generated in a separate binary. You could put this resource into a separate binary and then easily load and unload it via `registerResource`/`unregisterResource`.

`QFile` uses a virtual file system based on [`QAbstractFileEngine`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qabstractfileengine.html). The implementation of `QAbstractFileEngineHandler::create` acts as a filter and can catch the request and let your file engine handle it if desired. E.g. your file engine could simply fail on open - this is equivalent to deleting the resource.

Note that since Qt 5 the `QAbstractFileEngine` is not public anymore and presumably Qt folks are looking at replacing it with something else. To use these APIs, you need to add `qt += core-private` to your project's qmake file.

Comment: Thanks @kuba-ober! I'll take a look at the file engine and the `registerResource`, it will take me a time to test, but I'll let you know!

Comment: BTW, regarding the modifications the thing is that the client wants to _be able to migrate to future versions of Qt_, so I'd like to reduce the amount of work done in order to catch up with newer versions of Qt as fast as possible.

Comment: You could set up a private git source repository that tracks the qt base repository's designer folder. Use a [sparse checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114887/is-it-possible-to-do-a-sparse-checkout-without-checking-out-the-whole-repository) and a shallow pull to pull only the required code. Then add your changes to the repository. When it's time to upgrade to a newer Qt version, rebase your branch. You might get a few conflicts, but those will be only where Qt code and your code changes overlap. You can add that project as a submodule to your project's git repo. No git = SOL.

Comment: The `registerResource` suggestion was very helpful, thanks!