# Git - How to push new files to master without cloning

Tags: git, git-commit, git-checkout

I am in a strange predicament. The repository that I want to clone is too large so I've been using sparse-checkout to get specific files and folders that I need. Here are the instructions I followed to do this: [Is it possible to do a sparse checkout without checking out the whole repository first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4114887/is-it-possible-to-do-a-sparse-checkout-without-checking-out-the-whole-repository).

An example: I was able to checkout Folder 1 and Folder 2 from the repository.

```
Repository   
--> Folder1
--> Folder2
```

I now need to save a new folder with files into the repository. What is the best way to do this?

It would have to be structured like this:

```
    Repository   
    --> Folder1
    --> Folder2
    --> NewFolder
```

Comment: The standard git workflow should work (`git add`, `git commit`, ...), even for a sparse checkout. Did you try that and run into a problem?

Comment: I guess the problem I am running into is that I cannot do a sparse checkout because the path to the NewFolder that I want to checkout is non existent.

Comment: From the instructions I linked above, I tried doing "echo "NewFolder/*" > .git/info/sparse-checkout" and "git checkout master" but it returns "error: Sparse checkout leaves no entry on working directory".

Comment: `git add`, `git commit`, `git push` works for me in a sparse repo without adding the new dir to `.git/info/sparse-checkout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm moving this to an answer, because I think it will help for me to show you what I am suggesting so that you can tell me if I am not understand you.

> The repository that I want to clone is too large so I've been using sparse-checkout to get specific files and folders that I need.

Note that a sparse checkout only *partially* helps with this issue! Sparse checkout only control what shows up in your work tree; you're still cloning the entire repository.

> An example: I was able to checkout Folder 1 and Folder 2 from the repository.

I assume that you mean you have performed a sparse checkout of these two folders:

```
$ git clone --no-checkout https://git.example.com/myrepository
$ cd myrepository
$ git config core.sparseCheckout true
$ echo -e 'Folder1\nFolder2' > .git/info/sparse-checkout
$ git checkout master
```

So that your working directory looks like:

```
$ ls
Folder1 Folder2
```

You want to create a new folder.  You can do that simply by adding and populating the folder:

```
$ mkdir newfolder
$ echo 'Hello world' > newfolder/newfile
$ git add newfolder
$ git commit -m 'added a new folder'
```

Comment: Thank you. That really helped. It looks like I am able to commit the folder and files as normal.