# how to use git to track a single directory of a repo and show as top directory in work tree

Tags: git, perforce

I came from perforce background. There are client spec which allow p4 work tree has different directory structure from files in the depot. Now with git, I need files from two git repositories to build my project, say repo A and B.
I do not need everything in B, but I only need a sub-directory B/C, to placed in side work tree of A.

```
-A
 |--some--content-in-A
 |--other-content-in-A
 |--C
```

Currently, I use google repo to manage both A and B. My work around around is to check out entire B and copy C into its place by using directory copy from repo (an extention of file copy)

```
-A
 |--some--content-in-A
 |--other-content-in-A
 |--B
 |  |--other-content-in-B
 |  |--C
 |--C(copied from B/C)
```

What I really need is the capability of only check out directory C from repo B and put it in the top level. If I use sparse checkout, I can achieve only checkout directory C, but it will but in A/B/C instead of A/C.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35097530/git-sparse-checkout-without-leading-directories) is very similar to what I asked. But there is not solution yet.

Comment: found another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48422349/how-to-checkout-git-repo-subdirectory-into-current-directory) which is similar to what I need.