# git clone does not work when trying to clone a TensorFlow repository

Tags: git, github, tensorflow, git-clone

When I do

```
~$ git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/inception/inception
```

I get an error:

> Cloning into 'inception'...
>   remote: Not Found
>   fatal: repository 'https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/inception/inception/' not found

And the URL actually works when I paste it into my browser. So I am confused about what the problem could be here. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an incorrect inner URL. With Git you cannotclone selectively.

The correct URL should be,

```
https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git
```

The command is,

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git
```

Comment: I see, but if I want to clone the sub-directories such as `inception` do I still have to use the URL above?

Comment: @Huzo With git you cannot clone a part of the repository since git is a distributed repository. You have to clone the entire repository.

Answer (score 1):

> I see, but if I want to clone the sub-directories such as inception do I still have to use the URL above?

While you would still clone the full repo, you can do a [sparse checkout](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4909267/6309)

```
mkdir myrepo
cd myrepo
git init
git config core.sparseCheckout true
git remote add -f origin https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git
echo "path/within_repo/to/desired_subdir/*" > .git/info/sparse-checkout
git checkout [branchname] # ex: master
```