# Locally delete and ignore folder without commiting

Tags: git, version-control, gitignore

There is a folder in our repository that others depend on, but I would like to delete for my local working copy. I would like to make sure that I don't accidentally commit this change. If I just delete the folder, my git index is spammed with hundereds of deletions from that folder. Is there a way to make git ignore the deletion of that folder?

I tried adding the folder path to .git/info/exclude but that seems to be indendet to prevent local files from being commited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is no.  There's a longer answer that is *yes but*—specifically, yes, but be *careful* with this!  Specifically, you can set the *skip-worktree* bit in the index.  Git's *sparse checkout* mode uses this bit, and you can use it yourself for the same effect:

```
git update-index --skip-worktree <list of files>
```

though in this case you might want to just set up sparse checkouts in the first place.

#### Long

The index is indexing (hence the name *index*) your work-tree: it lists all the files that *should* be present, and has their content that will in fact be in the *next* commit you make, unless of course you modify the index before making that next commit.  I'll get to what *should be present* really means in a bit, but let's look at the normal case first.

If you remove all the files (and their containing directory / folder) from your work-tree, Git notices that your index and your work-tree do not match, and tells you that you have these differences, i.e., that all these files are deleted.  They are *not staged for commit* because the files *are* still in the index, and the copy of each file *in* the index matches the copy of each file in the current commit.  But they *are* missing from the work-tree: they *are* deleted.

If you remove the files from the index as well (using `git rm --cached`), your index and work-tree will now match up: the index won't list `dir/file`, and `dir/file` won't actually exist.  So this part of `git status` output will no longer complain about `dir/file`.  But if you do that, now your *current* commit, which Git calls `HEAD` or `@`, *does* have `dir/file`, and your index *doesn't* have `dir/file`, so the *next commit you would make* would also *not* have `dir/file`.  That means that a delete of `dir/file` is *staged for commit* and `git status` will report *that*.

In other words, if `dir/file` is missing from the work-tree, but is in `@` (the current or `HEAD` commit), you have only two options:

- `dir/file` *is* in the index.  Then it's deleted in terms of index-vs-work-tree.  `git status` will say so.
- `dir/file` is *not* in the index.  Then it's deleted in terms of `@`-vs-index.  `git status` will say so.

If you do not intend to make a commit that lacks `dir/file`, the former is clearly the better choice—but it's still noisy.

#### What *should be present* means

<sup>1</sup>Note that if the index says some file with path *P* should exist, and it does exist, all is well.  The file data in *P* in the work-tree matches, or doesn't match, the data in *P* in the index, and the file data in *P* in the index matches, or doesn't match, what's in the `@` or `HEAD` commit.

On the other hand, if the index says that the file with path *P* does *not* exist in the work-tree, but in fact that file *does* exist in the work-tree, then path *P* represents an *untracked file*.  This is where `.gitignore` and other exclude files come in: you can tell `git status` *don't complain about P* by listing it in a `.gitignore`.

The third case is of course the one you're looking at: the file with path *P* does exist in the index, but is missing from the work-tree.

#### Sparse checkouts and the skip-worktree bit

Git has built into it direct support for what Git calls a *sparse checkout*.  To do this, you set the configuration variable `core.sparseCheckout` to `true`, and list paths (or pathspecs) in `.git/info/sparse-checkout`.  For details, see, e.g., [Is it possible to do a sparse checkout without checking out the whole repository first?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4114887/1256452)  The [`git read-tree` documentation section on sparse checkouts](http://schacon.github.io/git/git-read-tree.html#_sparse_checkout) has more about this as well.

The way sparse checkouts *work* is that Git reads the entire commit into the index as usual, but instead of copying all the corresponding files into the work-tree, it only copies the *selected* files into the work-tree.  For the remaining files, which may or may not be in the work-tree—because Git won't look—it sets the *skip-worktree bit* in the index entry for that file.

When `git status` or other Git operations are scanning through the actual work-tree to see what's *really* there, if they come across an index entry with the skip-worktree bit set, they *pretend* that the file *is* there, with the contents listed in the index.  They assiduously avoid checking to see if the file really is there or not.  What the index claims, according to the skip-worktree bit, must be *assumed* to be true.

If you use sparse checkout, Git will maintain the skip-worktree bits by itself (to at least some extent—I have not experimented with the feature to see where it might have rough edges).  Otherwise you have to maintain them yourself, manually setting (`git update-index --skip-worktree`) and clearing (`git update-index --no-skip-worktree`) the bit for each file.