# Why git sparse checkout result in fatal error?

Tags: windows, git, github

This is my commands to `git` I am running in Windows to sparse checkout folders from repo:

```
git clone --verbose --filter=blob:none --no-checkout --depth 1 --sparse "https://user:password@github.com/organization/repo-name.git"

cd ./repo-name

git config core.sparseCheckout true

git sparse-checkout init
git sparse-checkout add /MainFolder !/MainFolder/Subfolder
git sparse-checkout add /AnotherFolder
...
git checkout --progress --force
...
```

and everything working perfectly on my machine (tm) but all the sudden it stop working on another Windows machine (in Powershell or CMD) with error:

```
fatal: specify directories rather than patterns.  If your directory starts with a '!', pass --skip-checks
```

I guess it is somehow in line: `git sparse-checkout add /MainFolder !/MainFolder/Subfolder` but what ?

After a lot of try/catches I found out that this command works OK:

```
git sparse-checkout add MainFolder
```

but this command  (with slash before folder name)

```
git sparse-checkout add /MainFolder
```

result in error: `fatal: specify directories rather than patterns (no leading slash)`....

What I need to set/configure on second machine so it continue to work as on my machine (including *!/folder* exclusion patterns) ?

P.S. Both machines using git version: `git version 2.37.1.windows.1`

---

@torek gave a correct answer but I want to add from myself:

There was a mis-understanding of what mode of sparse checkout is used. What is written above is a `pattern` style - so to make it work I must disable `cone` style like this:

```
git config core.sparseCheckout true
git config --worktree 'core.sparsecheckoutcone' false
```

and then

```
git sparse-checkout init
```

or just use `set' command instead all configurations commands like this:

```
git sparse-checkout set --no-cone
```

anyway - I must disable `cone` mode so above git commands will work (including the special symbols to exclude folders: `!` and other staff)
Thanks @torek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using the new *cone mode* feature of sparse checkout.

Sparse checkout has two modes now: *pattern mode* and *cone mode*.  Pattern mode is the old mode and is what you were using.  Cone mode is the new *default*.  It is much faster (or supposed to be much faster) and pattern mode is now deprecated.  However, cone mode is more restricted: there are some sparse checkout setups that are literally not possible in cone mode.

If you're not *depending on* pattern mode, you can simply leave out the leading slash.

For more information on this, see [the `git sparse-checkout` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout).

Comment: So - how this command: `git sparse-checkout add /MainFolder !/MainFolder/Subfolder` could be re-written in `cone` mode ?

Comment: Drop the leading slashes, and add the `--skip-checks` if needed, just as the command advised you to do.

Comment: The error is: `fatal: specify directories rather than patterns.  If your directory starts with a '!', pass --skip-checks` as I written in question. How to *exclude* folder from checkout process ? I guess git thinks that `!FolderName` - this is actually a folder name that include `!` sign - but it is not - it just my command to exclude it. How I can do that ?

Comment: In cone mode, you list only (and exactly) those folders that should be checked out, so make a list of the folders you *do* want. Note that this means you'll have to make a list of all the `MainFolder/subfolder`s; this will be the set you add.