# How to update branch with master when done a sparse checkout

Tags: git, merge

Repository am working on  is very huge. So I did a sparse checkout and working on folders that are required. Now I wanted to update branch with latest master code.

So here the question is: how to update branch with latest master when done a sparse checkout?

Comment: Did you try `git pull origin master`?

Comment: What happens when you apply new changes from master? What do you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have set your sparse-checkout file patterns (using the [`git sparse-checkout set or add`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-sparse-checkout/2.27.0#Documentation/git-sparse-checkout.txt-emsetem) command as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62999760/6309)), any future `git pull` would follow those patterns.

So that is the first command to check (`git pull`), using a Git recent enough (2.27+)