# Is it possible to clone subdirectory of github repo? error 'fatal: repository '<https://github.com/username/repositoryname>' not found'

Tags: github

When I am trying to clone a public repository I am getting below error

> fatal: repository 'https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/volumes/nfs.git/' not found.

I am trying to clone the following URL

```
https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/tree/master/staging/volumes/nfs.git/
```

instead of copying the repository

```
https://github.com/kubernetes/examples.git
```

I do not want to copy entire repository as there are lots of files. The necessary part is available on "staging/volumes/nfs".

will it work or do I have to copy the repository itself?

Comment: You can choose which files to include when cloning a repository, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository/52269934#52269934.

Comment: You should change your question title to *what you want to achieve* (i.e. cloning only a subdirectory of a git repo), instead of just the error message.

Comment: @Frizt edited my question title as suggested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subfolder inside a git repository is not a git repository itself. You have to clone the top level repository, because it contains the (hidden) `.git` folder, which is the *actual* repository containing the commit history etc.

What you want is a sparse checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60729017/1221661

Comment: @Jan Morawiec thank you for providing the solutions.