# Pulling just one directory out of a git repo

Tags: git, git-pull, git-checkout, git-fetch

I have a git repo that I want to do a pull from. I do a normal `git pull` with no problems. The issue is that I want just one certain directory out of the repo. My thinking was that I could use a `.gitignore` file with a rule like this:

```
#Ignore all files
/
#Except the one I want
!/temp
```

The problem is this doesn't work. Is that the right way to do it or is there a better way?

Comment: btw, to ignore all files, I'd go with `/*`

Comment: Just for the record: you cannot pull only one directory. You always pull the **history**, not files or directories. Of course, you a free to _work_ only on some files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pull specific directory with git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425059/how-to-pull-specific-directory-with-git)

Answer (score 51, accepted):

`git pull` fetches and merges the remote branch.

`.gitignore` works only locally, and will hide matching entries from showing up on `git status` and being added to the index with `git add`. It's not what you want.

What you want to do, is `fetch` the remote branch, and from that, extract the dir/file you need.

```
$ git fetch <remote> <branch>
$ git checkout <remote>/<branch> -- relative/path/to/file/or/dir
```

the file/dir should now be in your branch and added to the index.

Comment: Should that say `remove` or `remote` on the 2nd line?

Comment: Actually, depending on your situation, this solution will not work at all. Imagine the <branch> in first command was added after the local repository was cloned: the fetched commits will not be referenced by any local branch (not even by a tracking branch like `<remote>/<branch>`). `git fetch` will store the reference in `FETCH_HEAD`. Besides, `git checkout` will just modify the local tree and index. Afterwards, you'll have no idea where all these files came from.

Comment: No problem! I was going to edit myself but didn't try the command first! :D +1

Comment: @c00kiemon5ter, Is **git checkout <remote>/<branch> -- relative/path/to/file/or/dir** same as **git merge <remote>/<branch> -- relative/path/to/file/or/dir** ?

Comment: @Ninad: no, `git checkout` doesn't preserve history, `git merge` does.

Comment: I take it there's no way to fetch only changes to the relevant directory; all changes within each commit for the branch are fetched from the remote, even if some of those changes are checked out, right?