# How to tell git that my local directory is a specific directory in the remote tree

Tags: c++, git, version-control, bitbucket, working-directory

I have a shared git repository on bitbucket where I'm working on a part of a project and others are working on other parts. All the parts are each in a different folder
On git the folder structure looks something like this:

```
rootdir
  part_foo
  part_foo2
  part_mine
```

On my filesystem however The structures of my c++ project looks like this:

```
rootdir
  bin
  src
    file1.cpp
    ...
    fileN.cpp
  test_data
```

The `bin` and `test_data` folder are not to be commited as they are for my use only.

So what I'd like to achieve is to have the content of my local `src` folder to be synced with the content of `part_mine` folder.

I've tryed both [sparse-checkout](http://vmiklos.hu/blog/sparse-checkout-example-in-git-1-7) and the solution proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10124421/1338262), but they both are not the perfect solution as I end up having the `part_mine` folder created inside the `src` folder (or viceversa), which is kind of a problem for me.

So I'm asking if there's a way of telling git to think of my working directory as one specific directory in the remote tree. That would be that if I `init` and `remote` the git repository inside the folder `src` I can then tell git that I'd like to `push`/`pull` inside a specific folder (i.e. `part_mine`) and see all the file in there in `src` and viceversa.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual solution is to:

- clone the repo in some folder external to your project (no need for sparse checkout here, unless the repo is really *huge*)
- symlink `src` to `rootdir/part_mine`

For any git operation, you go to yourRepo (for git add, commit, push)

For the rest, you work in `rootdir` as usual.

Comment: This is a nice workaround, thank you...if no more direct answer is posted I'll mark this as solution.

Comment: I'd like to warn everyone that actually git do not handle symlinks as you might expect... I suggest to have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/954560/what-does-git-do-to-files-that-are-a-symbolic-link) for more details about the argument - **tl,dr:** symlinking `src` to `rootdir/part_mine` as suggested by @VonC works, but the other way around doesn't, so pay attention.

Comment: I agree, this is to be used from and for your project only. Your gir repo isn't aware of the symlink here.