# Git - checkout a single directory out of a repo - error: pathspec [directory path] did not match any file(s) known to git

Tags: git, github

I am trying to effectively check out only a directory and its contents (a specific wordpress theme directory) inside a [larger git repo hosted on Github](https://github.com/mrengy/new-urban-arts) on a server. The server has existing WordPress directories in it, and I want to place the new theme directory from the repo into the proper directory on the server. I first tried the approach described in [an accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10124421/370407) to a similar question. When I ran the below line,

```
[scapa]$ git fetch git@github.com:mrengy/new-urban-arts.git
```

I got an error of:

> fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount parent )
>   Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).

So I ran:

```
[scapa]$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/newurbanarts/stage.newurbanarts.org/.git/
[scapa]$ git remote add origin git@github.com:mrengy/new-urban-arts.git
```

Now when I run ([as per the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10124223/pulling-just-one-directory-out-of-a-git-repo/10124421#10124421)):

```
[scapa]$ git fetch origin master    
[scapa]$ git checkout origin/master -- wp-content/themes/newurbanarts
```

I get:

> error: pathspec 'wp-content/themes/newurbanarts' did not match any file(s) known to git.

What am I doing wrong, and how do I get around this?

Comment: What is the output of git log?

Comment: @Grisk fatal: bad default revision 'HEAD'

Comment: Sounds like the local head is just corrupt. Have you deleted .git and tried it again?

Comment: @Grisk Okay, I deleted .git and again ran the lines exactly as above in the question. When I ran `git fetch origin master`, the response was "From github.com:mrengy/new-urban-arts
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD". Then when I ran `git checkout origin/master -- wp-content/themes/newurbanarts` , the response was "fatal: invalid reference: origin/master"

Comment: Did you clone the repo or did you manually init and fetch?  It sounds like you never pulled down the branch contents. Also, you'll need to create a remote tracking branch before you can do anything.

Comment: @Grisk I did not clone the repo. I manually did init and fetch. The repo has a bunch of content that would overwrite other existing content on the server. So I only want to get a specific directory from the repo into the server. What exactly do I need to do to pull down the branch contents and create a remote tracking branch in this situation?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-git-repositorys-sub-directory-only/13738951#13738951

Comment: Whoops, didn't mean to comment just the url. Those should be the steps that you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after some back and forth in the comments, I think we've come to a solution here.

As it turns out, GIT does support the concept of checking out only subtrees of a given repository, through a process called 'sparse checkout' which you can find more information about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-git-repositorys-sub-directory-only/13738951#13738951).

The concept is to initialize a new, clean git repository, add your remotes, turn on the setting 'core.sparsecheckout,' and finally to check out your folders.