# Git pull only contents of a repository

Tags: git, version-control, github

Is there a way to only git pull the contents of a repository without pulling the home folder? For example I have a bunch of files in a repository called "sample" but I only want to pull the contents of "sample" into my local repository called "local." I do **not** want to pull "sample" such that I get: local -> sample -> [contents]. Is there a way to only pull the contents?

I'm asking because I am operating on a shared web server that requires that I place my content under a specific folder (and named certain file names within the folder).

Thanks.

EDIT: I wasn't being quite clear before. I'm working on a local machine such that I am **only** allowed to change the contents of my folder and not the contents of the folder that contains my folder.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pull specific directory with git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425059/how-to-pull-specific-directory-with-git)

Answer (score 2):

**Option 1::**

`git clone <repo_path> <folder name>`

So in your case, it would be `git clone sample.git local`

**Option 2::**

The folder-name where local repo is present does not have to be the same as that of the remote.

do a git clone ...

`git clone repo_pathOrURL`

then rename the folder

So for instance you have `sample.git` as your remote repository, do

`git clone sample.git`

This will clone the repository in a folder called `sample` on your local machine. Then just rename this folder to your liking, in your case `local`, and continue with the regular git pull and push.

Comment: I'm not allowed access to change the contents of the folder on the path before mine. Yes, it's a difficult system to work under.

Comment: ahhh yes, the first is great. Trying it out now. Thanks!

Comment: I'm now running into the problem of not being able to clone the repository because it is not an empty repository. Any suggestions on how to fix this so that I don't have to delete all the files in my directory?

Comment: what do you mean by "not an empty repository" ? maybe you can share the error message that you are getting?

Comment: fatal: destination path 'sample' already exists and is not an empty directory.

Comment: if you care about the changes that you made, then first push the change to the remote, then delete the contents of the folder, and then clone into the folder again. if the folder is empty you should have no issues in doing the git clone.

Comment: This worked for me. Also, if you cd to the dir you want to pull to, you can `git clone <repo_path> .`