# Pull only one directory or pattern with bzr

Tags: bazaar

I want to pull only one specific directory/file, or several directories/files which match a given pattern, from a bazaar repository.

**Is this possible? How?**

It is clear that I can pull the whole project and then keep only what I want, but this is not a suitable solution in this case.

Related threads:

[How to pull specific directory with git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425059/how-to-pull-specific-directory-with-git)

https://answers.launchpad.net/bzr/+question/120210 (old thread)

Answer (score 0):

Note that git will still fetch the full history, but it will only check out the files specified in the working tree.

You could do something similar in Bazaar with export:

```
$ bzr branch lp:blah blah
$ bzr export -d blah subdir blah/subdir
```

Or if you don't want the history:

```
$ bzr export /path/to/local/subdir lp:blah/subdir
```

Comment: So it means the answer to the question "Is this possible?" is "Yes"?

Comment: I think so; I'm don't think I'm familiar enough with all the the ins and outs of 'git checkout' to say for sure.