# How to fetch from remote repo from a particular folder, not whole repo?

Tags: git

My project consists of two main folders, `/client` and `/server`. `.git` forlder is top-level:

```
/app
  |-- /.git
  |-- /client
  |-- /server
```

And I have three branches

```
master
redux
prod
```

On `redux` branch I’m migrating an app to Redux.

On `master` branch there is current version of an app. Actually dev version.

I usually work on `master` and do these commands to update my local/remote repos. It updates both, `/server` and `/client`:

```
git push origin master
git fetch origin master
git merge origin master
```

As I’m working on `redux` branch and Redux migration, it's hugely not the same with current `/client` folder in `/master`.

The question is, how to fetch updates from `master` branch from `/server` folder only?

1) I'm on `redux` branch. Working in `/client` folder.

2) I push to `redux` branch.

3) But I need fetch from `master` branch from `/server` folder.

Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pull specific directory with git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425059/how-to-pull-specific-directory-with-git)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem possible to `git fetch` a specific directory. It only works for entire repositories. For reference, please check the [Git Fetch documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch).

Alternatively, you might want to instead `git pull` a specific directory from the current repo? In this case, you can have a look at the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4048993/1053915).