# How do I put my (mini code examples)projects to a specific folder in a single repo on Github?

Tags: git, android-studio, github

I'm building a portfolio of code examples. I don't want to put them in separate repositories. I want one repository with a folder called examples and put all the small projects in that folder. I created a repo on Github. And I've pushed the first code example there successfully. I then created a folder(called Examples) on Github (with a dummy file inside the folder)where I want to place my code examples.. How do I put the project in to the Examples folder?

Comment: Please show us the Git commands you used to try to push.  If you did this from the Android Studio plugin, then tell us how you configured that plugin, and what steps you took.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425059/how-to-pull-specific-directory-with-git

Comment: If you created the folder with a dummy file on GitHub, you need to pull the repo so that you have a local working copy, add your code examples to the folder in your working copy, commit the changes, and then push.