# How to handle multipul apps in git pull?

Tags: git

I have monorepo using lerna goes like:

```
apps
 angular-app-1
 node-app-1
 node-app-2
 node-app-3
packages
 pck-1
 pck-2
 pck-3
 pck-4
 pck-N
```

The relationship between apps and packages goes as follow:

- node-app-1 use: pck-1, pck-3
- node-app-2 use: pck-1, pck-3, pck-4
- node-app-3 use: pck-4
- node-app-4 use: pck-4, pck-1

I decide to do monorepo with `lerna` to share between packages and apps.

Is it possible to pull from the git just the app (for example: just node-app-2) without others apps? is anyway I can do to that?

Comment: I would not use lerna with Angular, [as there are better solutions available](https://nx.dev/).

Either way, it is not possible to do what you describe with a single git repository. You can look in to using git submodules if you have this requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something with help of this existing question:

[How to pull specific directory with git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425059/how-to-pull-specific-directory-with-git)

In your case it is multiple directories, but it should be possible this way.