# Clone specific folder from repository in simple-git

Tags: node.js, git

I just started using `simple-git` and I have a question: is it possible to clone all the files from one folder on a repository instead of the whole thing? My code is this:

```js
const simplegit = require('simple-git')
const git = simplegit()

const repo = 'https://github.com/PrinceKomali/bot-index/';
const path = './test';
const options = [];

const handler = () => {
    console.log('DONE')
};

git.clone(repo, path, options, handler());
```

Running this clones the entire repository but I only need the contents of the `pages` folder. How can I do this

Comment: I don't know what simple-git is, but you can find an answer with Git [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/git-how-do-i-clone-a-subdirectory-only-of-a-git-repository)

Comment: Maybe this SO post may help you in sometthing: [How to pull specific directory with git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425059/how-to-pull-specific-directory-with-git)

Comment: Thank you both, however I have seen these; I am just not sure how to implement them (https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-git)
I've found a solution that works for now but its pretty crude, involving `fs` and reading/copying/deleting folders

Comment: My scenario is to clone a branch to another Repo in node.js. do you know how we can use options in simple-git package.