# (Python) Is there a way to scrape an entire folder from github?

Tags: python, github, web-scraping

I'm currently working on a project, and so far I've been making it work by downloading the whole folder with the data I need from github on my local files and performing post processing from there. But if I want to post-process from the files directly from github so I can always have updated information, is there a way to get the folder I need into my script without manually downloading it?

Here's the repo, I need the entire data folder and it's composed of yaml files.
https://github.com/openstates/people/tree/main/data

Here's how I'm currently extracting files from my local.

```
def extractingOfficials(file):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        try:
            official = yaml.safe_load(f)
            return official
        except yaml.YAMLError as exc:
            print(exc)
            
def mainExtractingFunction(rootdir):
    all_yml_files = []
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
        for file in files:
            # skipping those who are retired and committees offices
            if "retired"  in subdir or "committees" in subdir:
                continue
            elif file.endswith(".yml") and "municipalities" not in file:
                all_yml_files.append(os.path.join(subdir, file))

    with ThreadPool(28) as pool:
        allofficials = pool.map(extractingOfficials, all_yml_files)
        pool.close()
    return allofficials
```

Comment: Why scrape when you can use `git pull` ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I need to get all the yaml files from the repo together into one dataframe, within one script. Sorry, I'm new to git stuff, can git pull help me achieve that?

Comment: Check [How to pull specific directory with git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425059/how-to-pull-specific-directory-with-git)

Comment: Beyond Git, Github has a [REST API](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents?apiVersion=2022-11-28) that can be used to retrieve files or folders

Comment: Just `git clone` the whole directory tree.  Now, all of those files are local to your computer, and you can play with them as you need to get them in memory.

Comment: Try: https://minhaskamal.github.io/DownGit/#/home?url=https://github.com/openstates/people/tree/main/data