# How to download only a sub folder from a repository using Git?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

My experience with git consists of about 4 hours reading github and bitbucket help pages and setting up my local repositories and ssh keys on my computer, so please excuse me if the answer is rather obvious.

I will use 538's [github](https://github.com/fivethirtyeight/data) as an example to ask my question.

On my local computer, once I initialize my git folder and have been added to the list of contributors, I know I can download a local copy of the whole folder.

However for example sake, lets say I was only interested in the [nba-draft-2015](https://github.com/fivethirtyeight/data/tree/master/nba-draft-2015) subdirectory.

From reading [How to pull specific directory with git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425059/how-to-pull-specific-directory-with-git) and [How to git-pull all but one folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416815/how-to-git-pull-all-but-one-folder/2416991#2416991) it appears that there is a way to just  download the sub directory folder.

Assuming the location or my repo locally is ~/repo, could someone give me what commands I would type into git for this specific example with the 538 data?

I have read the other SO pages and didn't completely understand the links and answers, so I think an example with the 538 page would help best illustrate it for me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there any way to clone a git repository's sub-directory only?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/600079/is-there-any-way-to-clone-a-git-repositorys-sub-directory-only)

Comment: @OSryx  It kind of is a duplicate, but I tried getting it to work, so I was looking for a more concrete example which I could modify for my own use. , rather than people directing me to help pages I've already read and couldn't get to work

Answer (score 0):

Well looking at that repository there are only two files,so if you just wanted those two files you could just download them, or use the steps from your links, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2466735/how-to-checkout-only-one-file-from-git-repository) *might* work too (I could not personally get it working).

I would pull a shallow clone `git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/fivethirtyeight/data.git`, it only takes a few seconds for me, because it doesn't get all the history, just the most recent change.

However, If you want to be a contributor I don't think you can just pull a part of it, I could be wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2303645/8395964 , seems that it is not possible:

> Note that sparse checkouts still require you to *download* the whole repository, even though some of the files Git downloads won't end up in your working tree.