# Pulling from a remote repo and ignoring a specific directory

Tags: git

We have an old project that we are upgrading. Considering the amount of refactoring that would be required for the frontend, we decided to clone the repo, delete the old front end code (i.e. delete the directory) and create a fresh directory.

Everything is working fine, but there is one issue that I overlooked. We are still making updates to the old repo. This is fine for the frontend code, but we need to keep the changes to the backend code in sync with the new repo. So I want to be able to perform a git pull on the old repo to fetch the changes, but ignore the frontend directory ( /react-ui ).

Does anyone have any ideas on how I might do this? I'm also open to suggestions on other methods for how best to handle the problem of needing specific code (or more accurately ignoring specific code) from another repo.

I haven't implemented anything yet, but from what I've researched the best options seem to be using sparse-checkout or potentially creating a submodule for either the backend or the new frontend.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2416815/how-to-git-pull-all-but-one-folder